# how do i sum of two floats and get a float value in decimal places?

Tags: javascript

when i add two numbers in javascript.e.g.,

```
var a = 4.0;
var b = 4.0;
var c = a+b;
```

When i print sum in console it gives 8, but i want 8.0, so i did this,

```
console.log(c.toFixed(1));
```

and when i checked

```
console.log(typeof c);
```

it gives output as string.
The problem is that i want output as number and with a decimal place.
Even the parseFloat() function did not help.

Overall what i want:

```
//input
a=4.0;
b=4.0;

//output
a+b = 8.0;
```

Comment: 8.0 is 8 as a number ... if you want 8.0 you can only have 8.0 as a string - javascript doesn't "know" you want 1 decimal ... what if you wanted 8.00, would it have to store that differently to 8.0?

Comment: A number has as many decimal places as you want - it only matters when you turn it into a string.

Comment: `typeof(c)` gives you `string`?

Comment: `console.log(8 === 8.0)`

Comment: where do you want a number with places?

Comment: Yeah, @JamesThorpe `toFixed` returns a string

Comment: @baao Indeed, but that's not what OP said in the post.  The claim is that `typeof(c)` itself is string.

Comment: This returns a number, not sure if that is what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/cmtvrkv9/2/

Comment: Ah... Yes it can be interpreted that way... :-) @JamesThorpe

Answer (score 4):

Try parseFloat() with toFixed()

```
var a = 4.0;
var b = 4.0;
var c = a+b;
console.log(parseFloat(c).toFixed(1)); -- 8.0
console.log(typeof c); -- number
```

Answer (score 2):

`toFixed` retuns a string. And it have to returns a string because this is only way you have to output something like `8.0`.

If you try `console.log(8.0)`, you'll get `8`. This is how the console output works and you can't really go against it.